# pyqt -- How to fix "QImage: out of memory, returning null image"

Tags: python, memory, pyqt, pyqt5, qimage

I've got some Python code where I'm drawing circles and lines, ... one some machines it returns a weird error message about being out of memory... but the system isn't out of memory from a task-manager standpoint. I've read elsewhere that there may not be enough contiguous memory for allocation (the RAM is fragmented). Checking the image dimensions, of around 16000 square, using `QImage.Format_RGB16` would yield an image of 512MB before compression (after which it is about 1 MB). I guess this could be an issue... but what can I do? De-frag the RAM somehow? Make Python/pyqt use a RAMDISK/swap? Why isn't the OS (Windows) handling swap and making the chunk of RAM available?

P.S. this is happening while running nosetests... so multiple tests may be calling this code... I wonder if the previous image isn't deleted fast enough by the garbage-collector between tests?

```
class QtDrawingTool(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.newImage = None
        self.qpainter = None
        self.qt_max_edge_dimension = 32767.0

    def get_max_dimension(self):
        return self.qt_max_edge_dimension

    def get_color(self, color_wanted):
        if color_wanted == 'white':
            color = QColor(qRgb(255, 255, 255))
        elif color_wanted == 'black':
            color = QColor(qRgb(0, 0, 0))
        elif color_wanted == 'blue':
            color = QColor(qRgb(255, 0, 0))
        elif color_wanted == 'green':
            color = QColor(qRgb(0, 255, 0))
        elif color_wanted == 'red':
            color = QColor(qRgb(255, 0, 0))
        elif color_wanted == 'yellow':
            color = Qt.yellow
        elif color_wanted == 'orange':
            color = QColor(qRgb(250, 158, 37))
        elif isinstance(color_wanted, tuple):
            color = QColor(qRgb(*color_wanted))
        else:
            raise Exception('color not available: {}'.format(color_wanted))
        return color

    def create_image(self, w, h):
        self.newImage = QImage(QSize(w, h),
                               QImage.Format_RGB16)
        assert(not self.newImage.isNull())

        # fill image with black
        self.newImage.fill(self.get_color('black'))

        # get a painter attached to our image data object
        self.qpainter = QPainter(self.newImage)

    def get_output_scaling_factor(self, width, height):
        # get a multiplier that will give our coordinates the most resolution relative to QT's maximum image resolution
        # return min(self.qt_max_edge_dimension/width, self.qt_max_edge_dimension/height)
        return 1.0

    def set_color_and_width(self, color, line_width):
        _color = self.get_color(color)
        the_pen = QPen(_color,
                       line_width,
                       Qt.SolidLine,
                       Qt.RoundCap,
                       Qt.RoundJoin)

        # the_brush = self.qpainter.brush()
        # the_brush.setColor(_color)
        the_brush = QBrush(_color)

        self.qpainter.setPen(the_pen)
        self.qpainter.setBrush(the_brush)

    def draw_line(self, src_x, src_y, tgt_x, tgt_y, line_width, color):
        # brush -- defines the color or pattern that is used for filling shapes.
        # pen   -- defines the color or stipple that is used for drawing lines or boundaries.
        self.set_color_and_width(color, line_width)
        self.qpainter.drawLine(src_x, src_y, tgt_x, tgt_y)

    def draw_circle(self, x, y, radius, line_width, color):
        self.set_color_and_width(color, line_width)
        self.qpainter.drawEllipse(int(x), int(y), radius*2, radius*2)

    def save_image(self, save_path, image_to_save=None):
        if image_to_save is None:
            image_to_save = self.newImage
        return image_to_save.save(save_path)

    @property
    def image_data(self):
        return self.newImage

    def get_flipped_along_y_axis(self):
        return self.newImage.transformed(QTransform().scale(-1, 1))

    def get_flipped_along_x_axis(self):
        return self.newImage.transformed(QTransform().scale(1, -1))

    def __del__(self):
        del self.qpainter
```

and here is the code from another class where I'm creating the image, and doing some drawing:

```
def draw_x(self, center_x, center_y, segment_length, color, line_width):
    self.graphics_backend.draw_line(-segment_length + center_x, segment_length + center_y,  segment_length + center_x, -segment_length + center_y, line_width, color)
    self.graphics_backend.draw_line( segment_length + center_x, segment_length + center_y, -segment_length + center_x, -segment_length + center_y, line_width, color)


def draw_dots(self, save_images=True):
    self.graphics_backend = QtDrawingTool()
    self.width = 16000
    self.height = 16000
    self.graphics_backend.get_output_scaling_factor(self.width, self.height)

    # set some widths, in pixels
    pen_width = 2
    dot_radius = 5
    dot_diameter = dot_radius * 2

    #add the dot diameter to the image size, otherwise some dots may be offscreen
    normalized_w = int(self.width * self.output_scaling_factor)
    normalized_h = int(self.height * self.output_scaling_factor)

    normalized_h += dot_diameter
    normalized_w += dot_diameter


    # Create image, 3 color channels
    self.graphics_backend.create_image(normalized_w, normalized_h)

    self.logger.debug("image dimensions: width: {}  height: {}".format(normalized_w, normalized_h))

    center_x = normalized_w / 2
    center_y = normalized_h / 2

    non_normalized_image_x_offset = 0 - self.minX
    non_normalized_image_y_offset = 0 - self.minY

    self.draw_x(non_normalized_image_x_offset, non_normalized_image_y_offset, 100, 'yellow', pen_width)
    self.draw_circle_near_origin()


    for item in self.items:
        for point in item:
            dot_coord = point.coordinates

            draw_x = (dot_coord.x + non_normalized_image_x_offset) * float(self.output_scaling_factor)
            draw_y = (dot_coord.y + non_normalized_image_y_offset) * float(self.output_scaling_factor)

            # Draw a red circle
            self.graphics_backend.draw_circle(draw_x, draw_y, dot_radius, pen_width, 'red')

    save_path = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(self.output_dir, 'dot_image.png'))

    if save_images:
        self.logger.info('Saving dot_image.png to: {}'.format(save_path))
        save_success = self.graphics_backend.save_image(save_path, self.graphics_backend.get_flipped_along_x_axis())
        self.logger.debug('save outcome: {}'.format(save_success))
```

Comment: maybe I should delete the image in the destructor? i.e.
    `def __del__(self):
        del self.qpainter`
to:
    `def __del__(self):
        del self.qpainter
        del self.newImage`

Comment: `would yield an image of 512MB before compression (after which it is about 1 MB).` Could you explain how you got to this? 16000*16000*16 (color depth) is about 4gb without compression. Also, where are you getting a 512 to 1 compression ratio?

Comment: 16000*16000*16 = 4,096,000,000 bits. 8 bits per byte yields 512,000,000 bytes, or 512 megabytes. When the images are saved with compression, they are around 1 megabyte on my filesystem.

Comment: You mention a few possible causes. I would try to find out which one is the culprit. See if you can pinpoint if it's a Qt issue, a garbage collection issue or a fragmentation issue. What happens if you allocate (and delete) a 512 MB Python bytearray just before creating the image? Run `gc.collect()` before each test to force the garbage collector to do a full collect. Circular dependencies may prevent objects from being collected. I would make test programs that do nothing but create a QImage or bytearray so that you're sure you don't have circular dependencies.